# How to use CardLayout with JPanels being created in different classes?

Tags: java, swing, oop, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am trying to create a simple Java Swing GUI application. I basically want a main menu with buttons that will display the rules and the games. Say I have 3 classes: Menu, Game, and Rules. Now, I want to create a JPanel inside each class for that specific GUI. I am having trouble figuring out how to use CardLayout to switch between the JPanels using the same JFrame. Does someone have a clear explanation for this? Should I create another class for the CardLayout? Thanks

Comment: It's likely just a matter of writing a method for each of the classes with a `getGUI()` (or similar named) method to return the `JPanel`. Having said that: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Show just one or, at most, two of these panel classes. If you can work it out with 2, the answer for 20+ should be obvious.

Comment: _I am having trouble figuring out how to use CardLayout_ Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html